# How to get return values when function with argument is called

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am writing below simple contract which stores all results of questionnaires of each ID.

```
contract answer{
  mapping(address => mapping(string => bool)) voters;

  struct qList {
    uint count; //The number of respondents
    mapping(address => mapping(uint => uint)) answer;
  }

  mapping(string => qList) questionnaires;

  function vote(string ID, uint qNum, uint ans) returns (bool) {
    if(voters[msg.sender][ID]) throw;
    voters[msg.sender][ID] = true;
    questionnaires[ID].count += 1;
    questionnaires[ID].answer[msg.sender][qNum] = ans;
    return true;
  }

  function getNumResult(string ID) constant returns (uint res) {
    return questionnaires[ID].count;
  }
}
```

The function "vote" including arguments can be called and mined successfully, howerver I cannot get the return value with the status message "Waiting for transaction to be mined..." in solidity-browser screen when I call "getNumResult" with ID which has already registered via the function "vote".

Appreciate it if someone would advise the cause of this and solution to get the return value of function with arguments.

Answer (score 2):

The author [also asked](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3285/how-to-get-return-values-when-function-with-argument-is-called) on the Ethereum Stack Exchange and here's one answer.

With non-constant function `vote`, you can only get the transaction hash back immediately because the transaction may never get mined.  Or it could take several blocks as indicated by "Waiting for transaction to be mined..."

Recommend to check: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/765/what-is-the-difference-between-a-transaction-and-a-call

### Events

Events are needed to get the "return value" of `vote`.

Example of how to add and trigger an `event`:

```
contract answer{
  // ...
  event VoteEvent(string ID, bool returnValue);

  function vote(string ID, uint qNum, uint ans) returns (bool) {
    // ...
    VoteEvent(ID, true);
    return true;
  }
}
```

See [Contract Events](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events) for the different ways to watch for and get event data using web3.js.